# Format input phone bumber, cant delete inserted data

Tags: javascript

I have javascript which formats inserted numbers to mobile format like +1 (222) 333 33-33. Everything seems to be working okay, but I cant delete whole inserted data, I can delete only 333 33-33 part of number, so this part +1 (222) remain untouched.

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = '+' + x[1] + '(' + x[2] + ') ' + x[3] + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="+1(222) 555-5555" />
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/RedEclipse/23pntueb/13/

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var length = 0;

document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  if(length <= e.target.value.length) {
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);

    e.target.value = '+' + x[1] + '(' + x[2] + ') ' + x[3] + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');

    length = e.target.value.length;
  };
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="+1(222) 555-5555" />
```

Create a variable to remember what the length of the text in the input field is. If, on input, the text length has decreased, then the user is removing text, so don't apply the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a solution for you (sorry), but the reason why you can’t delete the first parts is, that once you backspace to delete the space after the closing bracket, your listener then immediately inserts the space back in. So the next backspace again deletes the space (which is re-added), and so on.